# How I locate this element with Selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, xml, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
<div class="avg-stat" data-v-b401ba9e=""><span class="name" data-v-b401ba9e="">Pace</span> <span class="stat stat-color-great" data-v-b401ba9e="">142</span> <div class="vs-progress--background vs-progress-#35a936" style="background:rgba(53,169,54,0.1);height:13px;" data-v-b401ba9e=""><div class="vs-progress--foreground" style="background: rgb(53, 169, 54); width: 101.429%;"></div><!----></div></div>
```

I need help to locate this:

```
 <span class="stat stat-color-great" data-v-b401ba9e="">142</span>
```

I've tried this, but it didn't work:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/div[@class='avg-stat'][1]/span[@class='stat']")
```

Comment: try `//div[@class='avg-stat']//span[@class="stat stat-color-great"]`

Comment: You should be able to inspect the element in a browser and see its full xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Chropath](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo?hl=en) to find elements with xpath.

Answer (score 0):

The XPATH used by you is incorrect. Adding only `/` in the XPATH means you're starting from the root of the HTML document. For this case, you should try using the `//` at the start of the document as it allows us to start the search from anywhere within the document.

So, the expression would be :

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='avg-stat']/span[@class='stat stat-color-great']")
```